# What is causing a cyclic reference error in this code?

Tags: powerquery

I am following a blog post to merge two tables using a date within a range specified by another table. My two tables are `ContractReviews` and `Policies`, I want the policies table to be attached to each row of the contract reviews.

I have looked into what it is doing and I believe I have a good basic understanding, but I can't see why there is a cyclic reference? Is there anything obvious I am missing or could there be something else?

```ml
= #"Changed Type1" =
Table.AddColumn(ContractReviews, "Prof",
    (S)=> Table.SelectRows(Policies,
        (P)=> P[Insured]= S[Insured] and S[Date received]>= P[Inception Date] and S[Date received]<P[Expiry Date]
    )
)
```

I tried to read up on the code some more and what it is doing and believe I have a decent understanding. I tried changing some of the variables around and removing the extra conditions without any success.

---

Full Code:

```ml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ContractReviews"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date received", type date}, {"Broker", type text}, {"Insured ", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Prof",(S)=>Table.SelectRows(CAPolicy, each [Insured]=S[Insured] and Number.From(S[Date received]) >= Number.From([Inception Date]) and Number.From(S[Date received]) < Number.From [Expiry Date]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

New error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Function.
Details:
    Value=Function
    Key=Expiry Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell where the cyclic is coming from because you don't provide the full code.  Thats usually a sign you have referred to a previous step that doesn't yet exist or is the name of the current step. If you want, paste your full code in your question from home..advanced editor...

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date received", type date}, {"Broker", type text}, {"Insured", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type" , "Prof",(x)=>Table.SelectRows(Policies, each [Insured]=x[Insured] and x[Date received] >= [Inception Date] and x[Date received] < [Expiry Date]))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Sorry I've added the full code to the bottom of the post, thanks for your help - i've added the changes you've noted so far

Comment: Nevermind I found it was a missing bracket, thank you so much for your help

Comment: "*can't compare dates with < or >*".  I've never had any problems with that. `#date(2022,2,15) > #date(2023,3, 1)` => `false` and the inverse `#date(2022,2,15) < #date(2023,3, 1)` => `true`.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I did say what I meant, but perhaps I am mistaken. I've run into inability to use < > on date comparisons under various circumstances.  Unfortunately nothing immediately comes to mind  I'll edit my answer above to reflect your comment. Thank you

Comment: To be picky, we can reference the current step with an `@` (ex: `@step`. This make the definition of the step recusive. It can be handy to define a column where each cell is sum sum of the cell just upward and an other column to add. (An index column is handy to reference the column which is defined recursively). But this can work only if you don't try to calculate a single cell from itself. Ex: `CurrentStep = Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "sub_total", each if [Index]=0 then [to_add] else @CurrentStep[sub_total]{[Index]-1}+[to_add])`

Comment: Sorry, @Frédéric LOYER I am unsure what you are describing.  Please add your own answer to the question so we can all learn from it

Comment: @horseyride: it would be off topic to continue here with my idea, but you can read https://www.sinerj.org/~loyer/powerquery.html

Comment: Its not off topic. Just add an answer to the above question with your sample answer. I'd like to see an alternate method

Answer (score 0):

You have typed

```ml
Number.From [Expiry Date]
```

`Number.From` is a function and expect parenthesis to be called. Here, you apply `[Expiry Date]` as if it was a record or a table.

Just write:

```ml
Number.From([Expiry Date])
```

But note that you can compare 2 dates directly without converting them in numbers.

About cyclic reference, PowerQuery is happy with recursive expressions. Then we can write: `let a={42,@a{0}} in a` which returns `{42,42}`. But when evaluating a single value, it marks it as concurrently evaluated and if you need it to evaluate itself, a cyclic reference error is raised. Like `let a=@a in a`. Here the recursion is obvious since the `@` is needed to reference the variable we are defining. But `let a=b, b=a in b` imply mutual references and will produce such an error too. We can have this kind of issue with 2 queries, each one referencing the other (and need both queries to analyse what’s happening), or even with a single query whose the definition use reference its name.

See [http://www.sinerj.org/~loyer/powerquery.html](http://www.sinerj.org/%7Eloyer/powerquery.html) for an interesting usage of a recursive definition.

Since the `ContractReviews` is the name of the table, I guess it can also be the name of the query you were defining. Then you can’t use this result in its definition. If you do, evaluating `ContractReview` marks this variable as currently evaluated, then when you reference it raise an error. It is just an hypothesis since we have not the whole context of the first query. (Full code+name of the query).