# Using Power Automate to automate vlookup/data cleaning

Tags: powerquery, power-automate

I am looking for the best way to automate a task that I currently do manually via vlookup in Excel.

In one table, I have an export of contacts from a CRM system, like this:

> | Name | Email | ProductSlot1 | ProductSlot2 | ProductSlot3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | John | john@xyz.com | Car (Red) | Bike (Blue) |  |
> | Jane | jane@abc.net | Horse (Orange) |  |  |
> | Henry | hen@hen.com | Car (White) | Horse (Orange) | Bike (Blue) |

In another, I have the ‘lookup table’ I need to translate the ProductSlotX values so that they can be used as triggers for dynamic content in the email management system (because reasons).

This looks like this:

> | Product CRM name | Product EMS name |
> | --- | --- |
> | Car (Red) | Red Car |
> | Bike (Blue) | Blue Bike |
> | Horse (Orange) | Orange Horse |

Ideally, I’d want to upload an export CSV/Excel Workbook to a folder and have whatever method rewrite the values from CRM to their EMS equivalent and then spit out a cleaned CSV that I can then import into the EMS. This would look like this:

> | Name | Email | DynamicSlot1 | DynamicSlot2 | DynamicSlot3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | John | john@xyz.com | Red Car | Blue Bike |  |
> | Jane | john@xyz.com | Orange Horse |  |  |
> | Henry | hen@hen.com | White Car | Orange Horse | Blue Bike |

I’ve looked into Power Automate (cloud and desktop) and Power Query/BI, but have hit a dead end as they’re either too ‘on rails’ (i.e. want specified files) or where they let me use variables, the results are added as rows to one master table/sharepoint list, which would then require additional cleaning before I could download and import.

Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks in advance!

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

You can have the formulae which add a column :

```ml
AddColumn1 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "EMS Name", 
                    each if Text.Contains([ProductSlot1], "(") 
                         then
                           Text.BetweenDelimiters([ProductSlot1], "(", ")")
                           & " " & Text.BeforeDelimiter([ProductSlot1], "(")
                         else "error")
```

You should specify what happens if the form `Name (color)` is not respected.

If you want to rely on a `EMS mapping` table (you have to declare in PowerBI), you have:

```ml
Fusionned = Table.NestedJoin(Typed, {"ProductSlot1"}, EMS_mapping,  
                            {"Product CRM name"}, "EMS_mapping",
                            JoinKind.LeftOuter),
With_EMS_mapping = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Fusionned, "EMS_mapping",
                            {"Product EMS name"},
                            {"EMS_mapping.Product EMS name"})
```

This query has been done graphically (Merge query then On the new column, an expansion with only the `EMS name` column). I guess it will be easier like this than integrated my snipset in your query.

The `source` or `Typed` input table depends of your environment.

Comment: Note: This has been tested in Excel. I guess PowerBI will be compatible.

Comment: How does this create a CSV file and then write that out?

Comment: Also, please add your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866569/what-is-causing-a-cyclic-reference-error-in-this-code/75866767   I am interested in the solution you suggested in your comment

Comment: How to create a CSV file ? PowerQuery is a pure functional language and doesn’t export by itself a CSV file. But the tool which execute the query (Excel, PowerBI) should have an expirt function. I am only familiar with Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you have successfully tested this in Excel, is there a way to use the function via Power Automate so I can meet the requirement of having it spit out a cleaned CSV for me to use?